# Merge the two "merge user profiles" articles in the help center

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, merge-accounts, help-center

The help center article [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) reads:

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge) to do so. You will need links to the two profiles you would like to merge.

I would assume the link under "contact us" would point to the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact/other), but that's not the case; it points to another help center article, [Help > Merge user profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/contact/user-merge). This article can be found under [`/contact`](https://stackoverflow.com/contact), which, I assume, is why the first article uses the "contact us" verbiage.

Is there any point to the first article? Is there really any reason to have a help article that serves no other purpose but to point to another help article? I don't think so, and I think we should just remove the first article and have both links (the help center one and the `/contact` one) point to the second article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That /contact/user-merge page does have a form on it; it's just hidden behind a click.

This is one of the outstanding issues we'll be resolving this week. The whole /contact section is getting a redesign; this will make more sense once that design goes live. :)

**UPDATE:** The redesign of the "contact us" page is now live; /contact is now one consolidate page that contains a single email form to contact us. There shouldn't be any redundant instructions about user merges anymore. The Help Center article is still just a short page directing people to /contact, as that's the most expedient and reliable way to merge profiles.

Comment: Hm... My issue isn't with the /contact/user-merge page, but with the help center one: A couple of sentences that aren't much help, and just point to the /contact/user-merge one (which has a set of guidelines, and a link to the actual contact form). Will the help center one also be changed in the redesign?

Comment: @Yannis The help center one will be changed as well, but maybe not at the exact same time. The community team has told me that the instructions provided at /contact don't actually work in all cases, which is why I didn't copy them over to /help. Once we have guidance that will work for everyone looking to merge their accounts, the help center article will be where those instructions live.

Comment: Ah, ok then, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: The help center guidance is now our official correct instructions; there's no self-service merge anymore because it didn't work in a lot of scenarios and was rather buggy. Merging accounts must be done by contacting the team.